# Proof an combination related identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The identity is:
$$\sum_{n=L-p-1}^{L-1}\binom{L+1}{n+1}\binom{n}{L-p-1}(-1)^{n-L+p+1}-\sum_{k=p}^{L-1}\binom{k}{p}(-1)^p=1$$
where $p$, $L$, $n$ are non negative integers, and $0\le p \le L - 1$.

I wrote a simple c++ program to show it holds for some arbitrary $p$ and $L$ values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int fact(int n) {
   if (n == 0 || n == 1)
   return 1;
   else
   return n * fact(n - 1);
}

int combination(int n, int r) {
   return fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n-r));
}

int compute(int l, int p) {
    int item1 = 0;
    for (int n = l - p - 1; n <= l - 1; ++ n) {
        item1 += combination(l + 1, n + 1) * combination(n, l - p - 1) * std::pow(-1, n - l + 1 + p);
    }
   
    int item2 = 0;
    for (int k = p; k <= l - 1; ++ k) {
        item2 += combination(k, p) * std::pow(-1, p);
    }
   
    return item1 - item2;
}

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    const int l = 10;
    for (int p = 0; p < l; ++ p) {
       std::cout << "result for l = " << l << " and p = " << p << " is " << compute(l, p) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I was struggling to find a way to prove it.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seek to prove that

$$\sum_{q=L-p-1}^{L-1} {L+1\choose q+1} {q\choose L-p-1}
(-1)^{q-(L-p-1)}
= \sum_{q=p}^{L-1} {q\choose p} (-1)^p + 1.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{q=0}^p {L+1\choose q+L-p}
{q+L-p-1\choose L-p-1} (-1)^{q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^p {L+1\choose p+1-q}
{q+L-p-1\choose L-p-1} (-1)^{q}
\\ = (-1)^p {L\choose p+1} +
\sum_{q=0}^{p+1} {L+1\choose p+1-q}
{q+L-p-1\choose L-p-1} (-1)^{q}.$$

The sum is

$$[z^{p+1}] (1+z)^{L+1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+L-p-1\choose L-p-1} (-1)^{q} z^q.$$

Here we have extened to infinity owing to the coefficient extractor.
Continuing,

$$[z^{p+1}] (1+z)^{L+1}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{L-p}}
= [z^{p+1}] (1+z)^{p+1} = 1.$$

On the other hand on the RHS we also have

$$\sum_{q=p}^{L-1} {q\choose p} (-1)^p
= (-1)^p \sum_{q=0}^{L-1-p} {q+p\choose p}
= (-1)^p [z^{L-1-p}] \sum_{q\ge 0} {q+p\choose p} z^q
\\ = (-1)^p [z^{L-1-p}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{p+1}}
= (-1)^p {L\choose p+1}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Marko Riedel. It's very helpful.